# How does puppet decide if a node is active? (Changed)

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to change default behavior in puppet when a Notify resource is applied on a node. Current state (3.8) is that whenever the client is applying a simply Notify message, the client will send a report with state "Active". This is somewhat misleading because nothing really changed on the node.

Is it possible to change this so that puppet will not make a Notify resource change node status to "Active"? Thanks.

Comment: NMDV, but Puppet *doesn't* decide whether a node is active.  That's not an attribute of its reports.  It *does* report whether the configuration run failed, succeeded with changes, or succeeded without changes, but interpreting that in terms of whether a node is "active" is not a Puppet thing.

Comment: It is anyway strange to suppose that whatever software you're running on top of Puppet to interpret whether nodes are "active" would equate being active with having changed resources.  The possibilities I know about determine whether a node is active or not based on whether it is issuing catalog requests and/or sending reports on the expected schedule.  Whether any resources change during a given catalog run does not factor in to those evaluations.

Comment: Please take a look here
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1113
I think it will clear things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the [echo module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/ipcrm/echo) and refrain from using `notify` if this is a concern for you.